# Small sigma notation in Chen-Stein Method?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, notation, poisson-distribution

See the final line of maths in the segment below, from [this paper](https://dornsifecms.usc.edu/assets/sites/1193/docs/AGG.pdf) of Arratia, Goldstein and Gordon 1989.

$s_{\alpha}$ has a $\sigma$ used as part of its definition. This is some sort of notation not defined in the paper. What does it mean? Is it to do with a sum of what is in the brackets?

[image]

Comment: it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection of $X_\beta$'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s the sigma algebra generated by the random variables in that set, i.e. $\sigma(X_{\alpha}|\alpha\in J)$ is the sigma-algebra generated by all the $X_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha\in J$.

So the inner expectation is the conditional expectation, given that sigma-algebra.